# Do aromatic dienes undergo the Diels-Alder reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Do aromatic dienes undergo Diels-Alder reactions?

My understanding is that the $\pi$ bonds in aromatic compounds are not as localised as they are in other compounds, such as aliphatic dienes. Therefore, the dienophile shouldn't be as willing to go to these compounds. Am I correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Aromatic compounds are stabilized by their resonance energy. This means that the activation energy for reaction of an aromatic compound will typically be greater than that for a similar reaction of a non-aromatic compound.

That said, aromatics will react as the diene component in a Diels-Alder reaction if

- the dienophile is extremely reactive (*o*-benzyne for example)

[image]

- if the aromatic system is destabilized (for example by steric interactions or structural constraints) so that the resonance stabilization is decreased

[image]

- or if the aromatic system is large enough that loss of one aromatic ring does not significantly destabilize the entire system.  Anthracene is such an example where the middle ring will react *via* a Diels-Alder reaction.

[image]

([image source](http://organicsynthesisinternational.blogspot.com/2014/12/preparation-of-910-dihydroanthracene.html))

Comment: But then why does benzyne undergo the Diels Alder reaction with Furan? Both of them are aromatic! Is it because benzyne is highly unstable?

Comment: Yes, o-benzyne is a high energy species, therefore extremely reactive.

Comment: What is this o-benzyne? Is it any different from benzyne or are they just different names for the same thing?

Comment: there is **o**rtho-, **m**eta-,  and **p**ara-benzyne, depending whether the removed hydrogens are located 1,2, 1,3 or 1,4.

Comment: Does benzyne count when answering this question? Since the pi system involved in the cycloaddition is orthogonal to the aromatic pi system...

Comment: @PCK  Benzene, paracyclophane and anthracene are used above as examples of aromatic pi systems that participate as the diene componenet in a Diels-Alder reaction.  The in-plane ~ $\ce{sp^2}$ orbitals in o-benzyne are reacting as the the olefinic component of the DA reaction.